# Pandas groupby multiple keys selecting unique values and transforming

Tags: pandas, transform, unique, grouping

I have a data frame df=

```
Owner     Manager     Date      Hours  City
 John      Jerry       1/2/16     10    LA
 John      Jerry       1/2/16     10    SF
 Mary      Jerry       1/2/16     9     LA
 Zach      Joe         1/3/16     5     SD
 Wendy     Joe         1/3/16     4     SF
 Hal       Joe         1/4/16     2     SD
```

... 100,000 entries

I would like to group by 'Manager' and 'Date', then select unique values of 'Owner' and sum 'Hours' of that selection, finally transforming the sum to a new column 'Hours_by_Manager'.

My desired output is:

```
Owner     Manager     Date      Hours  City   Hours_by_Manager
   John      Jerry       1/2/16     10    LA   19
   John      Jerry       1/2/16     10    SF   19
   Mary      Jerry       1/2/16     9     LA   19
   Zach      Joe         1/3/16     5     SD   9
   Wendy     Joe         1/3/16     4     SF   9
   Hal       Joe         1/4/16     2     SD   2
```

I tried using pandas 'groupby' like this:

```
df['Hours_by_Manager']=df.groupby(['Manager','Date'])['Hours'].transform(lambda x: sum(x.unique()))
```

Which gives me what I want, but only because the value of hours is different between 'Owner'. What I'm looking for is something like this:
 `df['Hours_by_Manager']=df.groupby(['Manager','Date'])['Owner'].unique()['Hours']transform(lambda x: sum(x))`
Which obviously is not syntactically correct. I know I could use for loops, but I would like to keep things vectorized. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suppose there is another line with `Mary` as the owner, same Manager and Date, but with a different number of `Hours`, say 19. What should the result be? In particular what should the result be for `John`?

Comment: Hours is linked to the hours worked for 'Owner' on a particular 'Date'. The 'Owner' is always linked to a particular 'Manager'. So Mary would never have a different number of hours on a given date. The value of Hours would be redundant in that sense. That's why the result of 'Hours_by_Manager' is 19 for both instances of John and Mary because they are linked to the manager Jerry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['LA', 'SF', 'LA', 'SD', 'SF', 'SD'],
    'Date': ['1/2/16', '1/2/16', '1/2/16', '1/3/16', '1/3/16', '1/4/16'],
    'Hours': [10, 10, 9, 5, 4, 2],
    'Manager': ['Jerry', 'Jerry', 'Jerry', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe'],
    'Owner': ['John', 'John', 'Mary', 'Zach', 'Wendy', 'Hal']})

uniques = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Hours','Owner','Date'])
hours = uniques.groupby(['Manager', 'Date'])['Hours'].sum().reset_index()
hours = hours.rename(columns={'Hours':'Hours_by_Manager'})
result = pd.merge(df, hours, how='left')
print(result)
```

yields

```
  City    Date  Hours Manager  Owner  Hours_by_Manager
0   LA  1/2/16     10   Jerry   John                19
1   SF  1/2/16     10   Jerry   John                19
2   LA  1/2/16      9   Jerry   Mary                19
3   SD  1/3/16      5     Joe   Zach                 9
4   SF  1/3/16      4     Joe  Wendy                 9
5   SD  1/4/16      2     Joe    Hal                 2
```

---

Explanation:

An `Owner` on a given `Date` works a unique number of `Hours`. So let's first create a table of unique `['Hours','Owner','Date']` rows:

```
uniques = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Hours','Owner','Date'])
# alternatively, uniques = df.groupby(['Hours','Owner','Date']).first().reset_index()
#   City    Date  Hours Manager  Owner
# 0   LA  1/2/16     10   Jerry   John
# 2   LA  1/2/16      9   Jerry   Mary
# 3   SD  1/3/16      5     Joe   Zach
# 4   SF  1/3/16      4     Joe  Wendy
# 5   SD  1/4/16      2     Joe    Hal
```

Now we can group by `['Manager', 'Date']` and sum the `Hours`:

```
hours = uniques.groupby(['Manager', 'Date'])['Hours'].sum().reset_index()
  Manager    Date  Hours
0   Jerry  1/2/16     19
1     Joe  1/3/16      9
2     Joe  1/4/16      2
```

The `hours['Hours']` column contains the values we want in `df['Hours_by_Manager']`.

```
hours = hours.rename(columns={'Hours':'Hours_by_Manager'})
```

So now we can merge `df` and `hours` to obtain the desired result:

```
result = pd.merge(df, hours, how='left')
#   City    Date  Hours Manager  Owner  Hours_by_Manager
# 0   LA  1/2/16     10   Jerry   John                19
# 1   SF  1/2/16     10   Jerry   John                19
# 2   LA  1/2/16      9   Jerry   Mary                19
# 3   SD  1/3/16      5     Joe   Zach                 9
# 4   SF  1/3/16      4     Joe  Wendy                 9
# 5   SD  1/4/16      2     Joe    Hal                 2
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I don't understand what the call to reset_index() is doing?

Comment: `uniques.groupby(['Manager', 'Date'])['Hours'].sum()` returns a Series with a `MultiIndex`. But `pd.merge` expects 2 DataFrames. So in anticipation of wanting to call `pd.merge`, I converted the Series to a DataFrame, by calling [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). If you work through the code above in a Python interpreter, you'll be able to experiment and see the effect of `reset_index` easily.

Comment: I get it! Thanks again! How can I give you a gold badge :)